How would you TRIM the leading ZEROs from Time in Postgres
I have the following query that I am toying with:
SELECT
    to_char(date_trunc('hour', "TimeStamp"), 'HH12 AM') || ' - ' || to_char(date_trunc('hour', "TimeStamp")  + interval '1 hour', 'HH12 AM') as time,
    COUNT(*) as totals
FROM 
    eventtotals
WHERE "TimeStamp" >= NOW() - Interval '24 HOURS'
GROUP BY date_trunc('hour', "TimeStamp")

It displays the following output:
TIME                TOTAL
04 PM - 05 PM       300
05 PM - 06 PM       452
06 PM - 07 PM       393
07 PM - 08 PM       356
08 PM - 09 PM       356
09 PM - 10 PM       361
10 PM - 11 PM       359
11 PM - 12 AM       367
12 AM - 01 AM       357
01 AM - 02 AM       360
02 AM - 03 AM       286

I am aware of:
TRIM(LEADING '0'...

However, I would like to remove the leading zeros from the hours, I am just unsure of where to actually put the line for trimming in the above listed query, unless there is another way.

Use the "fill mode" modifier FM to trim leading zeros:
test=> SELECT to_char(timestamp '2024-11-12 20:00', 'HH12 AM');
 to_char 
---------
 08 PM


test=> SELECT to_char(timestamp '2024-11-12 20:00', 'FMHH12 AM');
 to_char 
---------
 8 PM    -- !!


Thank you Erwin, I was unaware of FM, going back to my original post and using
to_char(date_trunc('hour', "TimeStamp"), 'FMHH12 AM') || ' - ' || to_char(date_trunc('hour', "TimeStamp")  + interval '1 hour', 'FMHH12 AM') as time
Worked as well, thanks again.
